# Network Switch fast eneogh for Dlink DIR-655

Tags: switch

I am setting up a server and want to keep it outside of my local network which is inside of the Dlink 655 router.  I originally bought the dlink router mainly because it is fast, much faster than any other consumer router I have tried.  The only router which is capable of real 10MB/s d download speed.

I need a switch which will not cause a bottle neck to the router.  The switch will connect the to the server and the dlink router.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my SOHO environment D-Link DGS-2208, connected perfect to my DIR-655. Works well no issues to report.  nice price point as well, and same company.